# How to give Intent Data in Deep Link

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, deep-linking

I have updated manifest file to support deep linking. I have checked it from Run(Edit Configuration), and it opens the specified activity.

Now i need to send some data with the deep link. So what should be the procedure of it. I have added another data attribute, but i don't understand how to get data in the Activity in the same key/value fashion.

I am getting Intent like this in Activity

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
```

> intent.getData() has this value= myapp://videodeeplink

I have read some articles and tutorials regarding this, but i am just unable to get this. Kindly guide me how to put and get some data in deep linking.

> myapp://videodeeplink

```
<activity
    android:name=".VideosListActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="videodeeplink"/>
        <data android:scheme="videoURL" android:host="videoURL"/>
    </intent-filter>


</activity>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To send the data you should add pathPrefix parameter in your data tag like below, so that later we can parse it in the Activity/Fragment where you call it.

```
 <data
     android:host="@string/host"
     android:pathPrefix="path"
     android:scheme="@string/schema" />
```

Now when you want to parse it you can use pathSegments in Android, like below using the intents to obtain the data inside.

```
mainIntent = getIntent();
if (mainIntent!=null && mainIntent.getData()!=null
    && (mainIntent.getData().getScheme().equals("http"))){
        Uri data = mainIntent.getData();
        List<String> pathSegments = data.getPathSegments();
        if(pathSegments.size()>0)
        String prefix=pathSegments.get(0); // This will give you prefix as path
}
```

Comment: Thanks, then how will the end user create the deep link? Do we need to add prefix in deep link URL?myapp://videodeeplink/pathValue ?

Comment: what you can do is change your prefix as path/data1/data2/ . So when you will iterate over pathSegements list, use pathSegments.get(1) and so on to get your data & use myapp://videodeeplink/pathValue as a deeplink url

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this :)

Comment: One last question related to this, how to pass a long URL to Path, for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaaa

Comment: if you want to do that then its better to use PendingIntent and keep anything you want in your intent and associate the pending intent on click of the item.

Comment: 3 calls to getData() ...variables are cheap. Use them. :-D  (really though thanks for the example)